# Connectedness of Chow Varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety (possibly not irreducible). It's very well known that the Chow variety $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$ which parametrizes the $p$-dimensional cycles of degree $d$ is a complex projective variety which could be reducible. I would know more about connectdness. For $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ the Chow variety is connected (Algebraic Geometry - J. Harris, ex. 21.5). What about a projective variety $X\ne\mathbb{P}^n$? Is $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$ connected?

Comment: Typically the Chow variety is not connected.  In most introductory algebraic geometry textbooks, the first examples students learn are for $p=1$ and $d=1$ with $X$ either a smooth quadric surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (disconnected with each component isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$) or a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (the Chow variety consists of $27$ points).

Comment: Many thanks for this nice example Jason! :)

Comment: Dear Jason, I know it has been a while, but I would ask you if you know how to check that the Chow variety of $\mathbb P^N$ is connected. I would like to use a similar argument to see what happens in the case of connected varieties. Please let me know if you think I should post another question.

Comment: "... I would ask you if you know how to check that the Chow variety of $\mathbb{P}^N$ is connected."  Are you asking me to solve an exercise from Joe Harris's textbook?  I am willing to give a hint for that exercise: argue by induction on $N$ and consider the induced action on the Chow variety associated to a $\mathbb{G}_m$-action on $\mathbb{P}^N$ whose eigenspaces are (1) a point in $\mathbb{P}^N$ disjoint from the specified $p$-cycle and (2) a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^N$.